# Extra new-line on <samp> with `white-space: pre`, but not on <pre>

Tags: html, css, whitespace

In my code, the `<pre>` and `<samp>` tags are styled identically. Nevertheless, the `<pre>` block doesn’t start with a newline while the `<samp>` block does. How can I remove the newline? What’s causing the newline to appear? Why does it appear on one but not the other?

I’ve tried changing the `white-space` value to `pre-line` and `pre-wrap`, both to no avail.

```css
pre, samp {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  white-space: pre;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<pre>
&gt; This block doesn't start with a newline.
</pre>

<samp>
&gt; This block <em><u>does</u></em> start with a newline, despite having the same styles as the pre block.
</samp>
```

[Here it is in a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MindfulMinun/nxqf7cqz/).

Comment: What I found is that their `unicode-bidi` property is different, but this wasn’t helpful. Instead, the actual text content turns out to be different: `<samp>`’s `.textContent` does include a new-line at the start, `<pre>`’s `.textContent` _doesn’t_. There’s most likely no way to remove the new line other than to actually remove it in the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Xufox says, their text content is actually different. This is a consequence of the HTML parser. The rule for a `<pre>` start tag when in [the "in body" tree construction state says](https://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#the-in-body-insertion-mode):

> A start tag whose tag name is one of: "pre", "listing"
>
> If the stack of open elements has a p element in button scope, then close a p element.
>
> Insert an HTML element for the token.
>
> **If the next token is a U+000A LINE FEED (LF) character token, then 
>   ignore that token and move on to the next one.** (Newlines at the start
>   of pre blocks are ignored as an authoring convenience.)
>
> Set the frameset-ok flag to "not ok".

So an initial new line is dropped from a `<pre>` element, but there is no similar rule for a `<samp>` element.